# Individual Minimize Visibility for each Child in GWT Horizontal Panel

Tags: html, css, gwt

I have one Horizontal Panel created at fixed location left and bottom of page. I have elements added in Horizontal Panel (each element is a `VerticalPanel`).
I have show/hide (minimize) feature on each of those Vertical Panel child elements.
The issue I am facing is when I minimize one of the child, it minimizes but now allow access to backside elements of my main Horizontal Panels. Because even if one child element is in full view state (non-minimized state) it creates the whole horizontal panel height.

**GWT Page**

```
/* My Main Page Code */
<table class="myHorizTopPanel">
    <table ="childVPanel">
    </table> 
    <table ="childVPanel">
    </table>
    /* can be multiple of childs here */
</table>
```

Dynamically I am adding or removing child panels from top horizontal panel.

**CSS**

```
.myHorizTopPanel{
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background-color: #fff; /* I tried removing this but didn't work */
}

.childVPanel{
   bottom:0;
   height:200px; /*fixed height*/
}
```

I have minimize feature with each `"childVPanel"` in GWT code. (changing height to `30px`).
At this point the area of `"myHorizTopPanel"` remains as it is.
I want to set style or visibility to `"myHorizTopPanel"` in such a way, if any of child is minimized I can access the background main page.
Please suggest any solution on this.

Comment: So you want .myHorizTopPanel to change it's width based on its contents (myHorizTopPanel's width should be equal to the sum of it's children widths) Correct?

Comment: Yes. Width of myHorizTopPanel will be based on its child width. Its problem related to height. When I have multiple childs (i.e. say 3 A1, A2, A3) and the  second child (A2) is minimized at bottom. but still the height of entire panel remains same and I am not able to access Main Page even the child is minimized.